# Constraints for foreign keys like this in associative table?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

There are three tables A, B, C, **column src is foreign key in table A and B**. Table is the associative table for A.ID and B.ID.

Is there any constrains in mysql to make sure that **each row inserted into table C must follow the constraint: A.src equals B.src for their ID**.

For example, **in table C as below, `row 1 7` is allowed because both SRC for A.ID and B.ID are all 35, however `row 2 7` is illegal because SRC for A.ID is 46 but for B.ID is 35.**

```
Table A
ID  SRC
1   35
2   46
3   46

Table B
ID  SRC
6   46
7   35
8   46

Table C
A_ID    B_ID
1   7
3   6
```

Is there any constrains or mechanism can be set up to make sure each row inserted into table C is following the regular?

Thanks.

Comment: Oracle, MySQL and RDB, that's a very uncommon combination... Are you really using all those products?

Comment: I don't think it's uncommon, I'm using mysql currently and used Oracle before, I'm also interested if there is the constraint in other Relation-Database.

Comment: Don't just in case tag products not directly involved... Tag the dbms product you are using facing the problem. You may have noticed that MySQL's constraint handling is a bit different from Oracle's...

Comment: Yeah, you are right, mysql is focused, I know that the constraints are different between dbms. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I'm still don't get it, you said `table c` must follow the constraint: **A.src equals B.src for their ID.** But for you also said that `row 2 7` is illegal because **SRC for A.ID is 46 but for B.ID is 35.** If you see that `row 3 6` both have same **SRC**, thats mean there sould be `row 3 8`, `row 2 6`, and `row 2 8` in `table C`, right?

Comment: @JTR  Yes, you are right, `row 3 8`, `row 2 6` and `row 2 8` are all acceptable and can be inserted into, but don't means they must be inserted, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in Oracle using materialized views:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  SRC NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE B (
  ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  SRC NUMBER
);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON A
   WITH SEQUENCE, ROWID(id, src)
   INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON B
   WITH SEQUENCE, ROWID(id, src)
   INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW AB_MV
   BUILD IMMEDIATE
   REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT
   AS SELECT a.id, b.id 
      FROM   a, b
      WHERE  a.src = b.src
      GROUP BY A.id, B.id;


ALTER TABLE AB_MV ADD CONSTRAINT AB_MV__A__B__PK PRIMARY KEY (A_ID, B_ID );

CREATE TABLE C (
  A_ID NUMBER REFERENCES A( ID ),
  B_ID NUMBER REFERENCES B( ID ),
  PRIMARY KEY ( A_ID, B_ID ),
  FOREIGN KEY ( A_ID, B_ID ) REFERENCES AB_MV ( A_ID, B_ID )
);
```

**Inserting Data**:

```
INSERT INTO A
SELECT 1, 35 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 46 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 46 FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO B
SELECT 7, 35 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 46 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 46 FROM DUAL;

SELECT * FROM AB_MV;
-- Will return zero rows as there has not been a commit.

COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM AB_MV;
-- Will return 5 rows.

INSERT INTO C VALUES ( 1, 7 );
-- 1 row inserted

INSERT INTO C VALUES ( 2, 7 );
-- Fails with ORA-02291: Integrity constraint violated - parent key not found.
```

You can probably do a similar thing in MySQL using triggers to populate an `AB_MV` table (using `MERGE INTO` to enforce the uniqueness) - although a trigger for deleting rows from `A` or `B` might be interesting as the `ID` pairs can come from multiple `SRC` values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but I tried this

```
INSERT INTO table_c
(SELECT
   a.ID,
   b.ID
 FROM
   table_a AS a INNER JOIN table_b AS b ON a.SRC = b.SRC
);
```

[This](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23e426/1) works for me to insert ID from table_a and table_b to table_c

Comment: While this gets the acceptable values and inserts them into the table it completely misses the point of the question as it does not enforce that **only** values where there are matches to an acceptable pair in both tables `a` and `b` with the same `src` are allowed.

Comment: @MT0 Just as MTO@said, "it does not enforce that only values where there are matches to an acceptable pair in both tables a and b with the same src are allowed".

Comment: @JTR Actually table C is little meaningful if all available pairs are checked in because I can get it easily via A join B as your answer, right?

Comment: @jjs yeah, I thought so. My bad, sorry just ignore this answer XD